# Does the WinRT Clipboard History only support text and images?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm making a C++/WinRT app that makes use of the Window 10 clipboard history but for some reason I can only grab text and images.

My code is a bit like this..

```cpp
auto history = Clipboard::GetHistoryItemsAsync().get();

if (history.Status() == ClipboardHistoryItemsResultStatus::Success)
{
    auto historyItemList = history.Items();
    for (const auto& historyitem : historyItemList)
    {
        //Works
        if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats::Text()))
        {
            GetClipboardText(dataPackageView);
        }

        //Works
        if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats::Bitmap()))
        {
            GetClipboardBitmap(dataPackageView);
        }

        //Never triggers
        if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats::Html()))
        {
            GetClipboardHtml(dataPackageView);
        }
    
        //Never triggers
        if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats::StorageItems()))
        {
            GetClipboardStorageItems(dataPackageView);
        }
        //etc..
```

I'd like to make use of the other dataformats. EG: For StorageItems, I expected if I CTRL+C an item from my desktop or if I did it programatically with

```cpp
dataPackage.SetStorageItems({ std::begin(files), std::end(files) });    
Clipboard::SetContent(dataPackage);
Clipboard::Flush();
```

The file would end up in the clipboard history so I could handle it like in the first snippet. But the file never appears in the returned Clipboard::GetHistoryItemsAsync() container. I also don't see the file in the history viewer when you press WIN+V.

So what i'm wondering is;

- Does Windows 10 clipboard history "only" support raw text and images? can I not make use of the other dataformat properties? (ApplicationLink, Html, Rtf, StorageItems, Uri, Weblink etc)
- I gave StorageItems as an example but it happens with the other formats too. If I CTRL+C a weblink (such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), I expected dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats::WebLink()) Or Uri to trigger, but they don't
- If the clipboard history can support other formats, how do you actually make use of it?

Edit:
Forgot to add. When I programatically added a StorageItem to the clipboard I also tried it like below. Don't know why I can't add strings to an IVector though.

```cpp
auto options = ClipboardContentOptions();

auto formats = Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<hstring>();

formats.Append(StandardDataFormats::StorageItems()); //Unhandled Exception

options.IsAllowedInHistory(true);
options.IsRoamable(true);
options.HistoryFormats() = formats;
options.RoamingFormats() = formats;


Clipboard::Clipboard::Clear();
Clipboard::SetContentWithOptions(dataPackage, options);
Clipboard::Flush();
```

Comment: I checked this method and subscribed the HistoryChanged event, when I pressed CTRL+C on an file or used code to add it into DataPackage, the HistoryChanged event didn't trigger, this means it was not added to the clipboard history when we copied a file. In addition, when you pressed CTRL+C on a WebLink, It would be added to the clipboard history in the form of Text instead of WebLink.

Comment: Do you know why copying a file isn't being added to the clipboard history? The WinRT documentation and the code snippet I show at the bottom of my post gives the impression that this functionality should exist in Windows 10.. should I assume that currently Windows 10 isn't taking advantage of these features and only supporting text and images?

Comment: Also do you see anything wrong in the last code snippet? It doesn't compile for me but I'm assuming thats how you would force a storageitem to use the clipboard history? (sorry I didnt show it but dataPackage contains StorageItems)

Comment: You can set the files or folders contained in a DataPackage, however, when you add them into DataPackage or press CTRL+C, the HistoryChanged event won't trigger, it means it doesn't support adding the file to the clipboard history currently. In addition, the method of initializing IVector is incorrect, please using `auto formats{ winrt::single_threaded_vector<hstring>() };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As observed by my esteemed colleague Faywang - MSFT, Windows' clipboard history and cloud clipboard sync implementation supports only a limited number of clipboard data formats, and this is reflected in the UWP clipboard API in the Windows Runtime `Clipboard` class.

It's important to remember that what clipboard formats are supported by clipboard history is *not* a contractual detail of clipboard history. Please keep that in mind when you read on:

As of Windows 10 version 2004 (aka build 19041, aka the May 2020 update), clipboard history supports the following clipboard data formats defined in [`StandardDataFormats`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.standarddataformats?view=winrt-19041):

- Plain text: `StandardDataFormats.Text`
- Various URI formats: `StandardDataFormats.Uri`, `StandardDataFormats.WebLink`, and `StandardDataFormats.ApplicationLink`
- HTML clipboard format: `StandardDataFormats.Html`
- Bitmaps: `StandardDataFormats.Bitmap`

For compatibility with classic desktop applications (aka Win32 apps), clipboard history also supports a few clipboard data formats whose names are not in `StandardDataFormats`, but which the Windows system can auto-convert to and from the above-listed `StandardDataFormats` formats when needed by an app trying to paste a particular format.

Clipboard history does not support any other custom or well-known clipboard formats.

---

Given the above, the only thing I see in your results that seems strange is that your app doesn't appear to be reading the HTML format. I don't know of any Windows implementation bugs in this area - try fiddling with your code some more, and if you still have trouble, I'd definitely encourage you to post another question, or contact us at Microsoft another way (such as through Feedback Hub).

I do observe that the Microsoft documentation around clipboard history from a conceptual technical perspective is lacking. I'd also encourage you to file GitHub issues against the places where clipboard history *is* documented, such as https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api - we're always listening.

Comment: That answered alot. Thanks very much for replying!

Comment: As for the HTML format; I don't know if I was using it correctly. I was literally copy/pasting blocks of HTML code from VSCode and simply assumed Windows would recognise this. Instead it just always saw it as plain text.

Comment: That's likely expected; VS Code probably isn't setting the HTML Format for the clipboard item when you copy text that's HTML source code.

Comment: More specifically, when you copy text from VS Code, the editor by default copies a formatted version of the text with your syntax highlighting into the HTML clipboard format. If you turn off that option "Editor: Copy With Syntax Highlighting", then nothing goes into the HTML format at all.